# Outlook - strange item.Attachments error

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, vba

I have the following code, that should save a specific Excel file attached to an email. The code is combined with a rule, that triggers this script when an email with a specific subject is received.
The code is triggered, but here comes the strangest error I saw lately: itm.Attachments.Count appear  to be zero and obviously the file is not saved! But... if I put a breakpoint on "For each..." line and add itm.Attachments.Count to watch window, it is shown as zero. If I add itm only, then browse to Attachments property, then to Count property it shows 1 for Count (as it should) and the code is executed fine. I spent half a day trying to understand what's going on, but I can't figure it out.

The behaviour is the same both on a Outlook 2010 x64 on a Windows 7 x64 and on a Outlook 2010 x86 on a Windows 7 x86. Macros are enabled in Trust Center. I have attached some screenshot with the code and rule settings and also a movie showing the watch windows strangeness.

The script was built some time ago, it worked well on a couple of PCs and it was based on the steps from here: iterrors.com/outlook-automatically-save-an-outlook-attachment-to-disk/.
Any ideas?

Adrian

Rule screen here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw-aVIPSg4hsRFgxdzFtd3l1SkE/view?usp=sharing

1 min. movie here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw-aVIPSg4hsZERQWUJHLXd4bjA/view?usp=sharing

```
Public Sub Kona(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    saveFolder = "C:\test"
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        If InStr(objAtt.DisplayName, "Kona Preferred Fixed Price Matrix (ALL)") Then
            objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
        End If
        Set objAtt = Nothing
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I have scoured the internet for a solution to this problem, and no one seems to have proposed a solution, yet. Here's what I've come up with:

The Problem:
IMAP-Type Outlook Email Accounts do not download their Body and Attachments when they first arrive. Outlook experts everywhere will tell you you can adjust this in the Outlook Advanced Settings, but, they are wrong, that will have no effect.

Solution 1:
Switch to POP3. From a programming standpoint, this solves the problem, but my opinion is that if you can't do it with IMAP, then you're doing it wrong, right?

Solution 2:
Note that this is brute force, but it gets the job done.
In ThisOutlookSession:

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items
Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim objOutlook As Object
  Dim objNameSpace As Object

  Set objOutlook = Outlook.Application
  Set objNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

  'I am using this code on my gmail
  Set Items = objNameSpace.Folders("mathern29@gmail.com").Folders("Inbox").Items
End Sub
Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal objItem As Object)
    Dim objExcel As Object
    Dim objMsg As Object
    Dim Atmt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim Atmts As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim strFilePath As String
    Dim strBody As String

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    If TypeName(objItem) = "MailItem" Then
        Set objMsg = objItem
        If objMsg.DownloadState <> 1 Then
            objMsg.Display
            objMsg.Close (1)
            Set objMsg = Nothing
            DoEvents
            Sleep (1000) 'Need a pause or the loop runs to fast and kills Outlook
            RetryMailEvent objItem
        Else
            strBody = objMsg.Body

            Set Atmts = objMsg.Attachments

            For Each Atmt In Atmts
                If Right$(Atmt.FileName, 3) = "txt" Then
                    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                    strFilePath = "C:\temp\" & Format(objItem.CreationTime, "yyyymmdd_hhnnss_") & Atmt.FileName
                    Atmt.SaveAsFile strFilePath
                    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFilePath, 1)
                    strBody = strBody & "[Attatchment] " & objFile.ReadAll & " [/Attatchment]"

                    objFile.Close
                    Kill strFilePath
                End If
            Next Atmt

            'Any additional Code you want to run goes here

        End If
    End If
ProgramExit:
    Set objMsg = Nothing
    Set objExcel = Nothing
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

In a separate module:

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Sub RetryMailEvent(ByVal objItem As Object)
    Dim objExcel As Object
    Dim objMsg As Object
    Dim Atmt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim Atmts As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim strFilePath As String
    Dim strBody As String

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    If TypeName(objItem) = "MailItem" Then
        Set objMsg = objItem
        If objMsg.DownloadState <> 1 Then
            Set objMsg = Nothing
            DoEvents
            Sleep (1000) 'Need a pause or the loop runs to fast and kills Outlook
            RetryMailEvent objItem
        Else
            strBody = objMsg.Body

            Set Atmts = objMsg.Attachments

            For Each Atmt In Atmts
                If Right$(Atmt.FileName, 3) = "txt" Then
                    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                    strFilePath = "C:\temp\" & Format(objItem.CreationTime, "yyyymmdd_hhnnss_") & Atmt.FileName
                    Atmt.SaveAsFile strFilePath
                    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFilePath, 1)
                    strBody = strBody & "[Attatchment] " & objFile.ReadAll & " [/Attatchment]"

                    objFile.Close
                    Kill strFilePath
                End If
            Next Atmt

            'Any additional Code you want to run goes here

        End If
    End If
ProgramExit:
    Set objMsg = Nothing
    Set objExcel = Nothing
    Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Note: I became a StackExchange user just to share these findings with you. I you like it, please go forth and link other troubled souls with similar problems to here :).